# Understanding CMake phases

Tags: cmake

I'm writing CMake script that should do the following:

1. Make a static library.
2. Process the above library file using a python script.

Note that (2) should be done *after* the static library is built. As far as I understand, `add_custom_command` wouldn't work, because it's being processed during the configuration process. I tried to use `execute_process`, like this:

```
EXECUTE_PROCESS(
  COMMAND ${SCRIPT} --source /my/path/myLib.a --dest ${TEMP_DIR} 
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${TEMP_DIR} 
)
```

It also doesn't seem to work for 2 reasons: 1) it doesn't recognize the variables; 2) even if I put hard-coded paths, it gets invoked too early.

So what's the right was to accomplish the above sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's vice versa. **execute_process** during generation, **add_custom_command** during compilation. Just add it to target (POST_BUILD - **after** target is build):

```
add_custom_command(
    TARGET
    ${target}
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND
    ${cmd} # your python script
    WORKING_DIRECTORY
    ${YOUR_DIR} # command working directory
    COMMENT
    "your comments" # you will see this message, when python script invoke
)
```

Comment: Aha, great! So, if my target is defined as `add_library(MyLib STATIC ${MYLIB_SOURCES})`, then I can "bind" all additional commands to `MyLib`, like this: `add_custom_target(TARGET MyLib POST_BUILD .....)`, right?

Comment: By the way, does there exist a "build-time" variant of `FILE(GLOB ....)`, to populate a variable with a list of files - during the build phase?

Comment: No, I don't list source files, I concatenate static libs. That is: I build my static lib, extract object files from it and from additional 3d-party libs using python script (`ar` wont work due to duplicate *.o names), then `ar`/`ranlib` everything together - to make one big static library. Such a simple task that could be accomplished under Windows in 1 short line...